# SVN Rights Management Tool using Windows Authentication method

Tags: windows, svn, windows-authentication, visualsvn-server, authz

We're using VisualSVN Server as SVN server in Windows. But it has very limited abilities for managing rights. Also we couldn't use svn_access_file because our users are going to be authenticated using Windows Authentication method.

Is there any tool to manage rights that uses/supports Windows Authentication?

Comment: Limited abilities for managing rights? What exactly do you miss? You can always post your feedback at http://www.visualsvn.com/server/.

Comment: Hire **good admin**, baby!

Comment: @bahrep For example Reporting ability :) Our Project Manager need to know which user has access to which part of repository. There is such tools like http://svn-access-manager.org but we want to prevent from engaging php/apache/mysql directly :) [We're lazy and we know it]

Comment: @Sadegh you can use WMI in Powershell or VBScript to format such *access rules* report. Create a new StackOverflow question and specify the reporting tool requirements and I'll try to help you.

Comment: I think i can figure it out and doesn't seems that another question is required at this time :) I'll ask for help if there is any questions in future.

Comment: FYI: After upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.4 you will be able to use new PowerShell cmdlets to manage Subversion repository access rules. Check the updated answer below. E.g. `Get-SvnAccessRule` will output the list of permissions assigned on all repositories and globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it has very limited abilities for managing rights

It has **all** abilities, that Subversion has per se.

> we couldn't use svn_access_file

You can and must really, because Windows Authentication define only method of authentication, svn_access_file is **authorization** file and can refer and use usernames, obtained at authentication stage.

Comment: I know that there is authz file under %Repositories% dir, but not about authz-windows :P For limited abilities refer to comment replied to @bahrep

Answer (score 5):

**Update 03/09/2015:**

Managing path-based authorization rules for Subversion repositories is now possible through PowerShell. Check [VisualSVN Server | Scripting and Automation](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) page.

VisualSVN Server 3.4 and newer provides PowerShell cmdlets for server and Subversion repositories administration. Therefore, to manage access rules and automate such kind of tasks, you can use the following cmdlets:

- [`Add-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Remove-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Remove-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Select-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Select-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Set-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Set-SvnAccessRule)

> There are a lot of other PowerShell cmdlets introduced in VisualSVN Server 3.4. For the complete list of PowerShell cmdlets and usage examples, read
>   the article [VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).

---

Check [SVNBook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) and [VisualSVN KB article](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) for description of path-based authorization. This is not Windows Access Control, it's path-based authorization and you should understand the difference in order to configure and manage access rules correctly and effectively.

I'm confused by the question, in fact. VisualSVN Server has a nice GUI implemented as MMC snap-in, allows you to manage svn users / groups and access right via a familiar GUI. When you use Windows Authentication you manage users and groups via standard Windows / Active Directory tools.

Comment: It seems to me that we have to write a tool for implementing features like reporting on rights for an specific user; so WMI is one of choices we have to deal with. Thanks

Comment: @Sadegh Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 3.4 and run the command `Get-SvnAccessRule -AccountName DOMAIN\username`. You will get the list of access rules for a user `DOMAIN\username`.