# How to Create Visual SVN Repository and get that URL

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, visualsvn-server

I want to create the VisualSVN Server repository and get that repository URL in command prompt.  I need only that URL not any other information. can anyone help me?

I need command equal to VisualSVN Servers `New->Repository` and `Copy URL to clipboard`.

Comment: i want equal command to `new->repository` & `copy URL to clipboard` in visual SVN window...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2016:**

Upgrade to the latest VisualSVN Server version that includes a PowerShell module that adds a number of PowerShell cmdlets for Subverion server and repository administrators. Read [VisualSVN Server | Scripting and Automation](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) page.

The cmdlets should be very helpful in regular administration tasks and automation. Here is the complete list of VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets: [KB88: VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/).

As @IvanZhakov already suggested, you can create a new repository using [`New-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#New-SvnRepository) cmdlet.

Here is an example of creating a new repository MyRepository and grabbing its URL parameter:

```
$repo = New-SvnRepository -Name MyRepository
$repo.URL
```

**Outdated answer:**

I assume you mean VisualSVN *Server*, not VisualSVN extension for Visual Studio.

- You can create a repository with [`svnadmin create`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html) command or using VisualSVN Server's [WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provider. Here is the PowerShell command that creates a new repository "Repo1":

  `Invoke-WmiMethod -namespace root\VisualSVN -class VisualSVN_Repository -Name Create -ArgumentList Repo1`
- You can get URL of repository "Repo1" with the following PowerShell command:

  `Get-WmiObject -namespace root\VisualSVN -class VisualSVN_Repository | Select-Object -expandproperty URL | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Repo1"`

If you want to explore VisualSVN Server WMI provider, you can check it's MOF file which is located in the following folder "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\WMI" on the computer where
VisualSVN Server installed. Using this file as a reference you can write a program to manage VisualSVN Server on a various programming languages.

You may also want to check the MSDN article ["Using WMI"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks!, i'm new to WMI and PowerShell, if we want to create a new repository in 'c:\ drive' with name Repo1 what will the PowerShell command to do this. I had tried this `Invoke-WmiMethod -namespace C:\new\VisualSVN -class VisualSVN_Repository -Name Create -ArgumentList Repo1` in powershell, its shows error message that `Invoke-Wmimethd` is not recognized as a function. what type method we want to use for this case.

Comment: what does that root means whether local path or server. you had used back-slash(\) so i used local path. we want to mention anything else.

Comment: @Ramesh you should check MDSN links I've specified, it can be tedious but definitely worth it; namespace part points to VisualSVN Server WMI provider and is not related to your filesystem.Via WMI you can create repositories in repositories root location only ("C:\Repositories", by default).

It also looks like there is a typo in your command.

Comment: thanks!, i had created the repository and i got the url. but i didn't have access to import data into it. i want to give access `*=rw` . i had tried `-EnableAllPrivileges`, `-Authentication` but i didn't got the right one.

Comment: @Ramesh Managing Subversion repository access permissions via WMI is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14686167/761095

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with latest VisualSVN Server 3.4.0: it includes Powershell module for managing Subversion server. Just run PowerShell 3.0 and execute the following command:

```
$repo = New-SvnRepository -Name repo
$repo.URL
```

You may use `Get-Command -Module VisualSVN` to get list of all VisualSVN Server cmdlets.