# Adding Active Directory Group to visual SVN repo and granting read,write permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am new to VisualSVN commands. I am trying to add Active directory Group(Entire group) to 1 of the repository of SVN and give them read , write access to that repo using powershell commands. 
I have refered the link [SVN Rights Management Tool using Windows Authentication method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684522/svn-rights-management-tool-using-windows-authentication-method/14686167#14686167[1])

This is regarding rights to "USERS" .how can I grant permissions to entire "Group" using powershell commands( where users can be added later)

Comment: Have you tried simply using a group SID instead of a user SID?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers                                                                                 Yes I have tried using SID of group . It is giving InvokeWMI management Exception when I use Invoke-WmiMethod and InvokeMethodOnNull exception when I used setSecurity.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 3.4 and use the [`Add-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule) PowerShell cmdlet to add a new access rules for the Active Directory group account.

For example, if you need to add the ReadOnly access rule to `/trunk` or a project in a repository, run the following PowerShell command:

```
Add-SvnAccessRule MyRepository -Path /trunk -AccountName DOMAIN\MyGroup -Access ReadOnly
```

Read the article [VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/) for more information.